# Methods which are better or alternative to Self Organized Maps to get basic understanding/relationship of the data

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization, k-means, som, self-organizing-maps

I have been working on the concept of Self Organized Maps to get an understanding/ relationship of variables in any type of dataset and produce some heatmaps. Is there any other machine learning concept/method that can be used to perform an exploratory analysis on the data  and get a realtionship between variables.

Comment: som is a unsupervised learning algorithm. so, you can try other unsupervised learning algorithms. Look for other clustering techniques.

Answer (score 5):

There are no "best" techniques to visualize data. But there exists many algorithms that will give you different perspectives on your data. SOM belongs to a class of techniques known as nonlinear dimensionality reduction. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction) gives a list of 26 such techniques.

I see from your profile that you are using Python, so I suggest that you take a look at the [scikit-learn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html). They implement quite a few of those algorithms.
A fairly popular algorithm is [t-SNE](http://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/), which was created with visualization in mind. See the examples section for results on many popular datasets.

Finally, you don't have to limit yourself to this class of methods. They are really good when dealing with high dimensional data, but if that is not your case, much simpler methods will work well. Any clustering algorithms can be used to perform exploratory data analysis.